# AngularJS Services call .asmx webservice - TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, http, asmx

I am very sorry to ask this question. I am very sorry if my question is not clear. I am trying to call .asmx webservice from my AngularJS Services.

In my AngularJS Services, I have the following code snippet:

```
    .factory('BoothDesignatedCoordsService', ['$http',function ($http) {


return {
    // Might retrieved from db eventually
    fnGetBoothDesignatedCoords: function (strBoothName, intFloorPlanID) {
        try
        {
            var JSONObj = {
                BoothName: strBoothName,
                FloorPlanID: intFloorPlanID
            };
            var sendToWS = JSON.stringify(JSONObj)
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert("error from fnGetBoothDesignatedCoords " + e)
        }



        $http.post('http://localhost:4951/wsIPS.asmx?op=fnGetBoothDesignatedCoords',  sendToWS).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data)
                alert("Post Data Submitted Successfully!");
        }, function (response) {
            alert("Service not Exists");
           alert(response.status);
           alert(response.statusText);
            alert(response.headers());
        });


    }

}

 }])
```

In my .asmx file, I have the following code snippet:

```
       [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]

          public void fnGetBoothDesignatedCoords(string objJSONRequest)
    {
        wsIPS objRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<wsIPS>(objJSONRequest);
        string strBoothName = objRequest.ClientBoothName;
        string strFloorPlanID = objRequest.ClientFloorPlanID;
        int intFloorPlanID = int.Parse(strFloorPlanID.ToString());


        double[] arrBoothDesignatedCoords = new double[0];
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IPSConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        string strCommandText = "SELECT DesignatedCoords FROM Booth WHERE Name = @Name AND FloorPlanID = @FloorPlanID";
        SqlCommand selectCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
        selectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", strBoothName);
        selectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FloorPlanID", intFloorPlanID);
        myConnect.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = selectCmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            string strBoothDesignatedCoords = reader["DesignatedCoords"].ToString();
          arrBoothDesignatedCoords = Array.ConvertAll(strBoothDesignatedCoords.Split(','), double.Parse);
        }
        myConnect.Close();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(arrBoothDesignatedCoords));
    }

}
}
```

Note : my .asmx web service is running, so I can use the url to access it directly on my local computer.

However, I receive alert error that say "service not exists", and the error code is 500, and it is internal server error. And the console log gives me this error: TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value. Can someone please help me?

This is the screenshot of my .asmx webservice and its url:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it something wrong with my webservice url?

Comment: This happens when you try to convert object/derived data type into string or any primitive data type

Comment: so what should i do? Can give me the full answer please?

Comment: Where do you get this error browser console or server console any can you share full error that might help

Comment: Browser console. But i also receive the error alert that says service not exists

Comment: service not exists is ur alert console.log(response) to see actual error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134730/discussion-between-antoni-and-vinod-louis).